# Ordering by US credit card in London

Tags: uk, online-resources, payment-cards

I'm from the US, using a US credit card in London to order a pizza online.  It's not accepting my zip code (You must enter a valid postcode registered to your card).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try entering the postcode of where you want the pizza delivered.

Comment: Try a different pizza company?

Comment: @pnuts Thinking that either a) it would take any valid postcode or b) it only looked like the postcode was related to the card.

Comment: Chances are whoever designed the site figured only UK users, so has the script check to make sure the postcode matches UK format, which US zipcodes do not.  Go for Plan B, call your order in.

Comment: See if they accept PayPal

Answer (score 5):

Very likely you can't solve this problem. The online merchant very likely uses an [AVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Verification_System) authorization because the fees are lower this way.While it is possible to run an authorization without AVS (for example [entering 99999 into a New York City MTA ticket vending machine](http://web.mta.info/metrocard/mvms/) triggers this -- however that's a "card present" authorization from an entity which has *slightly* bigger transaction volume than your average pizza parlor so it has better chances of negotiating good rates on card acceptance) it depends on what sort of agreement exists between the online vendor and the gateway. You can of course use the delivery address and hope the pizza place only runs the card number - expiry date (and likely the CVV2 code) and not AVS. There's little harm in trying really (a hold might stay on your card for a few days if it fails but let's hope the price of the pizza won't push you over the credit limit).

Comment: Even so: Just Eat revenue in 2015 was <0.25B GBP, the MTA pulled in $7.7 billion in fare and toll revenue aka 30 times as many.